# WPF Datagrid horizontal scrollbar binding error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using a WPF Datagrid in my application with a custom style. When I scroll horizontally in the DataGrid, I get the following binding error:

> Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='-0.0857142857142854' BindingExpression:Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='grdSizes'); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Now I understand that it means that a button gets a negative value from the CellsPanelHorizontalOffset. I do not know what produces this negative value, though. I am not doing any offset calculations in my overriding DataGrid.

I also have this

```
<Button
    Name="btnLeftColSelectAll"
    Command="{x:Static g:DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
    Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type g:DataGrid}}}"
    Template="{StaticResource SelectAllButtonTemplate}"
    Focusable="false"
    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static g:DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static g:DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type g:DataGrid}}}" />
```

Button in my custom DataGrid style. This does not produce any binding problems with the width, although it is bound to the same property. I don't even know which button causes the problem, because this is the only button in my application which has its width bound to that property.

Another note: this binding error is only produced when I click on the scrollbar and drag it around. Everything is fine when I scroll around using the right and left arrow buttons.

Any ideas what causes this problem? Is this some WPF/.NET bug?

Comment: if this can still be reproduced and is still a problem could you try and comment that entire `Button` and see if the error still occurs? If it does try and find the real cause, if it doesn't could you show us every other control that is bound to `CellsPanelHorizontalOffset`?